# Yii2 Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch, yii2

How do we implement elastic search in yii2. Done with installation, How do I search by database using elastic search. So far followed [this link](http://www.cloudways.com/blog/using-elasticsearch-with-yii2/). Can anyone post if where and how to use it for our search functionality in the yii2 project.